# Prove that a total measure |$\mu$| is the smallest measure for the following

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Assume that we have a signed measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$ and a Hahn decomposition $(P,N)$ for $\mu$, then we define $|\mu| = \mu^{+} + \mu^{-}$ where $\mu^{+}(B) = \mu(B \cap P)$ and $\mu^{-}(B) = \mu(B \cap N)$ for each $B \in \Sigma$.

I have managed to show that $|\mu(B)| \leq |\mu|(B)$ for each $B \in \Sigma$, but would also like to show that $|\mu|$ is the smallest unsigned measure on $(X,\Sigma)$ that makes this possible.

So if I pick an unsigned measure $m$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ such that $|\mu(B)| \leq m(B)$ and need to show that $|\mu|(B) \leq m(B)$.

Since $m(B \cup P) \subseteq m(B)$ and $|\mu|(B) = \mu(B \cap P) - \mu(B \cap N)$, I guess I have to make use of this but I am not sure how to go further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mu ^{+}(B)=\mu(B \cap P) \leq |\mu(B \cap P)| \leq m(B \cap P)$ and $\mu ^{-}(B)=\mu(B \cap N) \leq |\mu(B \cap N)| \leq m(B \cap N)$. Hence $|\mu|(B)=\mu ^{+}(B)+\mu ^{-}(B)\leq m(B \cap P)+m(B \cap N)=m(B)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your wisdom.